# How is use of npm to install global packages that don't even get used in Node applications justified?

Tags: node.js, npm, google-chrome-app

My knowledge of `npm` is this:

It is a package manager for `Node.js` applications. What this means is that when you need someone else's library/package for your node application you can conveniently use `npm` to get those dependencies.

But I recently came across this command:

`npm install -g cca`.

Then I enter `cca` in my terminal and now it starts some program.

Now my question is how can `npm` install packages that can be accessed via the terminal?
I mean all packages installed by `npm` should be accessible by node application code (in JavaScript). This confuses me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like your primary question is not *how*, but *why*?

The distinction here is between a node *package* vs a node *module*.

Only *module*s are meant to be `require()`ed by other node applications, and not all *packages* on `npm` need be *modules*.  There are very many useful node packages that are only indirectly related to node.  E.g., `gulp` or `grunt` or `cordova` or `cca`, etc.

These answers come (reworded) directly from the [npm faq](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-faq.html)

For `cca` specifically, we hope to have a node *module* in the future, so the question of "why npm" is just forward thinking.  Additionally, `cca` is a downstream distribution of `cordova` (just like `phonegap`) which was always hosted on `npm`, and we wanted to continue that heritage.

Answer (score 6):

`npm install` is a complicated command -- it has (at least) three major functions:

1. From inside of a Node package (that is, a directory with a `package.json` file, or some subdirectory of it), running `npm install` installs all of that package's declared dependencies. It sticks these downloaded packages inside of a `node_modules` directory, and they are all available by the application's JavaScript code.
2. Again, from inside of a node package, running `npm install <package-name>` will download and install a named package from the npm package repository. It will, again, place it in the `node_modules` directory, so that it is available to that application.
3. From anywhere, running `npm install -g <package-name>` will download and install a named package **globally**. This means that it gets installed to your system's node_modules directory, and is available for all node packages to use.

The third usage, with -g, is also used for command-line utilities (as opposed to libraries). When installed with -g, packages can do things like installing new commands in /usr/local/bin, or installing man pages. These commands are then available to be run from a shell.

This is what `cca` does when you install it, and is the reason that we recommend installing with `-g`; so that you can use the `cca` command to create applications from anywhere, not because it is a kind of packaging utility.

Comment: okay. But in the example I mention, the package `cca` has nothing to do with Node after its installed, right? I don't see why npm comes into the picture here.

Comment: Sorry -- I hit `enter` before I was finished -- hopefully the remainder of the answer answers your question. `cca` is installed globaly so that the command line utility can be used from anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But isn't it weird npm is used for purposes like installing `cca` that directly execute from the shell? Why are `cca` developers shipping their package via `npm` of all tools? `cca` isn't even related to Node.

Comment: `cca` is a Node.js application (not just a library). The tool is written in JavaScript and runs under Node. As you said, `npm` "is a package manager for Node.js applications. It's a cross-platform way to install Node apps.

Comment: Also note, Isaacs has blessed any JS packages inside npm regardless of whether they are meant to be consumed by other node apps as libraries.  This includes, but is not limited to, libraries meant for use only in a web browser (i.e. via browserify), and cli tools like grunt or gulp or cca.

Answer (score 3):

- See [@mmocny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22770820/45375) for ***why* `cca` is a (global) `npm` package**, despite not containing modules for use in JavaScript code.
- This answer shows ***how* global `npm` packages work**.

---

**npm packages installed globally, with `-g`, typically contain executables** (whether binary or not) that are to be added to a folder expected to be in your system's `$PATH` in order to **make them globally available in your shell (from the command line) - independently of Node.js**.

As `npm help folder` puts it succinctly (emphasis mine):

> - Install it **locally** if you're going to **`require()`** it.
> - Install it **globally** if you're going to **run it on the command line**.

**Global package installation roughly works as follows**:

Note: What directory `{prefix}` represents varies by platform (e.g., `/usr` on Linux) - you can query its value with `npm get prefix` or `npm prefix -g`.
The *default* Node.js installations on Unix systems install to *shared* locations, so that root privileges (via `sudo`) are required for installing packages globally.
By contrast, if you are using Unix-based multi-version managers such as [`n`](https://github.com/tj/n) or [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), `{prefix}` may be a *user-specific* directory such as `~` or `~/.nvm/v0.10.28`, so that root privileges are *not* required for installing packages globally.
The following description is based on *Unix* platforms, with differing behavior on *Windows* noted separately, where needed.

- Global **packages** are installed in a package-specific subfolder of `{prefix}/lib/node_modules` - e.g., `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`.
- *Symlinks* to the **executables** from the package's `bin` subfolder (typically; as defined in the `"bin"` property of the package's `package.json` file) are then created in `{prefix}/bin`, e.g., `usr/local/bin` - which is what makes them globally available, given that `{prefix}/bin` is assumed to be in the `$PATH`.

  - *Windows*: `.cmd` batch files are used in lieu of symlinks, and they are placed directly in `{prefix}` (which is added to `%PATH%` during installation). These batch files are created based on analyzing a given executable's *shebang line* and explicitly invoke it with the interpreter found there, allowing for a seamless cross-platform experience.

- **`man` pages** from the package, if defined, are symlinked to `{prefix}/share/man`, e.g., `/usr/local/share/man`

  - *Windows*: `man` pages are not installed at all.

See also http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/

Answer (score 1):

The -g option makes it a "global" package, which provide global commands. These are used for modules like build managers (for instance grup). These are modules that are used in the same way over multiple projects, therefore they are "global" modules.

I am not sure however why they would use the -g option for cca, since cca seems to give you project specific functionality, not something like project management.

Comment: after `cca` is installed how is it even related to Node?