# Firebase init command on linux not working

Tags: linux, angularjs, node.js, npm, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to upload my page on angularJs to firebase hosting and when I run the command 'firebase init' doesn't do anything and I've read that this command would be create a 'firebase.json' file.

I follow the steps on the page of firebase hosting https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/deploying.html so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I think that the error could be the instalation of the nodejs or something like this, although I follow the steps fot his installation in many sites.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors as a result of `firebase init`?  Could you be more specific about what you mean "doesn't do anything".

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645220/firebase-tools-bash-firebase-command-not-found