# firebase command not found

Tags: firebase, ubuntu, firebase-tools

I am new to firebase and I'm trying to install it on Ubuntu.

I've used `npm install -g firebase-tools`,

when I run the command `firebase init` I get `firebase: command not found`.

I've looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645220/firebase-tools-bash-firebase-command-not-found), `npm get prefix` gives me `/usr` .

So I added `export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"` at the end of `.bashrc` file, But still same problem.

I also tried `` alias firebase="`npm config get prefix`/bin/firebase" ``, But there is no firebase folder under /usr/bin at all, so it also fails.

when I search for `firebase` folder, it is located at `~/.npm/firebase`.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Try adding a ~/.profile file in your home folder and copy paste this into it: export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

Add this at the TOP of your `.bashrc` file NOT the bottom.

```
export PATH="/home/your-username/.npm-global/bin:$PATH" # Add npm bin PATH
```

or

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"
```