# Firebase cannot be used after installation

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-cli

I just installed Firebase. NPM was previously installed and works. Node too. If I want to use Firebase in terminal, the command is not found. Firebase has been installed in the AppData/... folder. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are confusing the '[firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase)' package for the '[firebase-tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-tools)' package. The 'firebase-tools' package is what allows you to run firebase commands in your terminal. You can install the firebase-tools package by running `npm install -g firebase-tools`

Check out more details about the 'firebase-tools' package [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I installed the Firebase tools using the command. But unfortunately, I still have the problem. They can't be found.

Comment: In that case, check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645220/firebase-tools-bash-firebase-command-not-found) for the steps to manually add it to your path.