# “-bash: firebase: command not found”

Tags: firebase

I accidentally installed firebase-tools and initialized my app in my home directory. Now when I try to use firebase command in the correct directory, I get the error

`-bash: firebase: command not found`

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling firebase-tools in both my home directory and the correct directory with and without `-g`. I've also added this line to my `.bash_profile` per the advice of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645220/firebase-tools-bash-firebase-command-not-found/35037456#35037456):

`export PATH="/Users/myusername/.npm-global/bin:$PATH"`

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Trying looking at this thread which might help. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76649789/command-not-found-firebase-login-firebase-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76649789/command-not-found-firebase-login-firebase-tools)

Answer (score 1):

Run this command to see what you should be putting in that PATH prefix in your .bash_profile file:

npm get prefix