# deploy firebase functions on jenkins: firebase: command not found

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-functions

I would like to deploy Firebase cloud function on Jenkins but it responds "firebase: command not found".

Here is my execute shell on Jenkins

```
chmod 755 ./DeployCloudFunction.sh
./DeployCloudFunction.sh
```

but it output
`DeployCloudFunction.sh`: line 3: firebase: command not found

And this is the `DeployCloudFunction.sh` below

#!/bin/bash
firebase use myProject
firebase deploy --only functions

When I run `DeployCloudFunction.sh` on the terminal on mac, it's working perfectly. I have no idea why it goes wrong when run on Jenkings.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that firebase was installed under a different version of npm. For example, you may be using npm 12.19.0, but firebase is installed to npm 10.10.0. Then firebase will not recognize the command.

To fix this, install firebase-tools globally:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Or you could just try  adding the npm bin folder to your bash PATH variable. To do that, run:

```
npm get prefix
And it should output something like /home/your-username/npm-global. Then in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile (if you're in a Mac) file, add:
export PATH="/home/your-username/npm-global/bin:$PATH" # Add npm bin PATH
```

Or try running code below with terminal,

```
alias firebase="`npm config get prefix`/bin/firebase"
```

Note : One of the above solutions should work and should be tried in the same order I have written in the answer.

Adding this [Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/113) and [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645220/firebase-tools-bash-firebase-command-not-found) for more information.

Comment: I've tried the first and the third solution but it's still the same(run .sh file on mac terminal is ok, but not through Jenkins). since I am not familiar with mac, the second I still need time to try, thanks.

Comment: Can you have a look at this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/continuous) and follow these steps. See if that helps you?

Comment: @Scozirge2 Were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: Sorry, give me more time, I got something in a hurry need to do. I will check the documentation recently.

Comment: Any chance you got to try the solution?